# ActiveAndroid and Gradle Wrapper

Tags: android, gradle

I know this is confusing however I have read on multiple posts how to rectify my error that I am having. I hope. When I try to run my first activity, I get this error due to me using the active android library:

```
java.lang.String com.activeandroid.TableInfo.getTableName()
```

I have read online that this is due to me using a higher version of Gradle.(classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2') and that people have had success with version 1.5.0. Here is my issue, what must I put in Gradle Properties file to downgradle to the level of gradle as I am not sure and have had errors while trying to do this?

Comment: 'downgrade not downgradle'

Comment: That's not an error, it's a method.  What is the error message?

Comment: you gonna laugh at downgradle or no